# how to implement this procedure

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have implemented the first part of this problem but failed to achieve the second part. What I'm trying to do is that I have two vectors

```
std::vector<double> A = {1,1,2,2};
std::vector<double> B = {3,3,4,4,5,5};
```

I have to go through two loops and make subtraction of two math vectors. For example,

For the first iteration:

```
C = [1;1] (Note: the first two elements of A vector)
```

Because C is 2x1, I have to construct from B three math vectors of the same size, therefore the output for the first iteration is

```
1 - 3
1 - 3
------
1 - 4
1 - 4
------
1 - 5
1 - 5
```

For the second iteration, the C matrix is expanded by two elements per iteration , therefore the new C matrix is `C = [1;1;2;2]`. Now we need to make the subtraction again, the output for the second iteration is

```
1 - 3
1 - 3
2 - 4
2 - 4
------
1 - 4
1 - 4
2 - 5
2 - 5
------
1 - 5
1 - 5
2 - 3
2 - 3
```

As you can see, the second math vector is shifted by two elements where the first math vector remains as it is. 
A and B matrices have this assumption `size % 2 = 0`  where 2 is the size of C matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replicating your ouput, for first iteration you would have:

```
std::vector<double> A = {1,1,2,2};
std::vector<double> B = {3,3,4,4,5,5};
std::vector<double> C (A.begin(), A.begin()+2);

// bg - index of group of 2 elements in B
for (int bg = 0; bg < 3; ++bg) {
  for (int ci = 0; ci < int(C.size()); ++ci) {
    // bi - index of element in B
    int bi = (2*bg + ci) % int(B.size());
    std::cout << C[ci] << " - " << B[bi] << std::endl;
  }
  std::cout << "------" << std::endl;
}
```

For second iteration you would have to change one line:

```
// line changed...
std::vector<double> C (a.begin(), a.begin()+4);
```

---

Edit: OK, here's more general form that outputs both cases you specified for the change of iteration counter `it`. Hope it works when you extend the vectors.

```
for (int it = 1; it <= int(A.size())/2; ++it) {
  std::vector<double> C (A.begin(), A.begin()+it*2);

  // bg - index of group of 2 elements in B
  for (int bg = 0; bg < int(B.size())/2; ++bg) {
    for (int ci = 0; ci < int(C.size()); ++ci) {
      // bi - index of element in B
      int bi = (2*bg + ci) % int(B.size());
      std::cout << C[ci] << " - " << B[bi] << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "------" << std::endl;
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer however it doesn't work if I increase `A` matrix. For example, `A = {0,0,1,1,2,2}` and `B = {3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6}`. I gave an example but in my project, A and B are not fixed.

Comment: I have changed some of the parameters and now it is working. Thank you so much.